# Pipenv with coverage ignores kill

Tags: linux, bash, kill, pipenv, coverage.py

In a bash script I run coverage in a chalice project through pipenv. But the `.coverage` file is not created. The file is normally created after a gracefull end of the process. But `ps aux` shows, that the process lives after the script ends. When running the first line in the terminal and aborting with `Ctrl+C` everything works fine

```sh
python3 -m pipenv run coverage run --source=chalicelib $(pipenv --venv)/bin/chalice local --stage test --no-autoreload --port 8003 >chalice.log 2>&1 &
echo "$!" > chalice.pid
# here some e2e tests run
kill -INT $(< chalice.pid)
```

Comment: The [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) here is obvious, the subshell created for the background job receives SIGINT before performing redirections (The MRE for this would be `: >x & kill $!`; this sometimes creates `x`, sometimes doesn't). Why do you send that signal immediately after creating the job?

Comment: I don't do this. this was just an example. In between, there runs a e2e test.

Comment: If the execution of `pipenv --venv` takes longer than the *e2e test*, `chalice.log` won't be created; this is expected behavior.

Comment: the e2e tests take around 2 Minutes. I don't think this is the case here

Comment: The problem seems to be, that kill doesn't kill the process and therefore `.coverage` is not created, as this is only created after a gracefull kill. So maybe the Topic is not correct anymore. I updated the Topic and the explanation to the focus.

Comment: If this is a pipenv/python specific issue I can't help any further. Good luck